# Can I use a custom class method on NSArray to return a constant?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, nsarray, class-method

I frequently need to refer to an array of strings (let's say team names) in multiple places. The contents of that array to not change.

To achieve this, I defined my own class, `MyConstants`. In the header I am defining some unrelated constant strings and numbers. In the implementation file, I made the class a singleton, and then added a class method `arrayOfTeamNames`.

To access the array, I use [Constants arrayOfTeamNames].

I this acceptable?

I was thinking about how NSString and NSArray themselves handle creation via class methods. If, for example, I want an empty array, I can use `[NSArray array]` - so presumably 'array' is a class method on NSArray.

Therefore, instead of my above implementation, should I be using a category to add '+arrayOfTeamStrings' to NSArray, instead of using my own class?

Or, alternatively, should I create my own subclass of NSArray and add the class method there?

In either case, do I need to make the class a singleton myself? Or is this not necessary?

Comment: Seems like your over thinking it and if you keep worrying about it you might have a stress attack. What you have seems fine and if you are really worried about something else changing your already immutable array setup sometime of property setter type method.

Answer (score 0):

In general, there can be very good uses for adding class methods to foundation classes via categories. But in this case, I would actually stick with `arrayOfTeamNames` being part of `MyConstants`. The fact that Team Names is an `NSArray` isn't as important as the fact that it's a constant for your application.

If the values defined in `MyConstants` are very diverse and unrelated, or if there are only a couple of them, then I would consider just getting rid of `MyConstants` as a class and using categories or even just externs, e.g. `extern NSArray * const BPAllTeamNames`.